# Ideal size of the opera mobile for windows simulator

Tags: jquery-mobile, opera-mobile

Ideal size for testing jQuery mobile website in Opera mobile simulator ?

When I set it to 350 * 600 my application look great but when I make it smaller or larger it looses some text [not alignment]

Comment: I would think it would be the device screen size you would want to test for

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that designing for a fixed screen size will break. You could use Mediaqueries so your Web site will adjust to different screen sizes. See [Mediaqueri.es](http://mediaqueri.es/) for examples. And the article on [how to use mediaqueries](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/)